# SSRS Customized Error Page

Tags: reporting-services, error-handling

I wish to achieve the customize the error page.
However for the detail error like parameter not valid, processing aborted error which in the dashboard frame.

Anyway to customize this error?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customise the errors that are returned.  You can enable remote errors to display the error message to users that are viewing your report via the Report Manager, though this is generally not advisable.